# Python running multiple independent pieces of code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, parallel-processing

I am facing a small issue in my code. I have a main function that, given a certain condition arises, has to launch one or more different functions which deal with web scraping, in particular they use Selenium. The problem is that I would simply like to launch this web scraping "task", which is simply a python function, and not wait for it to terminate, rather let it go on independently from the rest of my code, so that I might be independently running 5 different instances of the same function, without waiting for them to terminate.
Some pseudo code:

```
while True:
    condition = SomeComputation()
    if(condition):
        IndependentFunction( some_parameter )
```

Once IndependtFunction is called, I would like to not have to wait for it to end. I have looked at multiprocessing, but from what I understood I might not need such type of parallelisation.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are network-bound, then pick multithreading. If cpu-bound, then pick multiprocessing.  If you do not care about performance, I would pick multithreading to avoid dealing with pipes.  There are lots of tutorials for both.

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846697/2359945

Comment: You may want to take a look at [async](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need multithreading in order to do that. The basic usage of threading module on par with your independent function could be like this:

```
 import threading
 while True:
     condition = SomeComputation()
     if(condition):
         newThread = threading.Thread(target=IndependentFunction, args=(some_parameter,), daemon=True)
         newThread.start()
```

That `daemon=True` argument means that the thread will execute fully independently, and the main program will not wait for it to finish what it is doing before quitting the program entirely.
Check [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) page for a more detailed tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You can upvote my answer and/or accept is as default answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not depending on the output of that **scraping** then you could use threading

it would be like

```
mytask = threading.Thread(myfunction,args=(arg1,arg2,argn,))
mytask.start()
```

more details documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to be exactly what I was looking for!